# "Failed to set ISR" on Raspberry PI 4

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi, 32bit

I'm trying to execute a compiled software on a Raspberry PI 4. When I execute it, I see this error message:

```
Failed to set ISR
: No such file or directory
```

Has anyone come across this message?

I did not find the answer in google.

Comment: perhaps the `compiled software` is faulty, or at a guess not compatible with your system - where did you get it? what OS are you running?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So far I used 32bit raspberry pi OS.  (Bookworm). After I updated it yesterday, compiled software did not work. Today I tried to change the OS to 32bit legacy (bullseye?) then it worked.

Comment: when you say "compiled software", what software do you mean